# Why won't angular's titlecase filter work for me?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

I am writing an AngularJS single-page app.

In the index.html file, I have the following lines:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
</script>
```

I have defined a controller name MyController. This controller has a variable named `my_name` which contains the string "HELLO". The controller works with an HTML template file called `my_fragment.html`. Here is what that HTML file looks like:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as myCtrl" class="full_screen_container">
    MyString = {{myCtrl.my_name | lowercase}}
</div>
```

It works. The output in the browser looks like this:

```
MyString = hello
```

But now, I don't want `my_name` to be lowercased. 
I want it to be [titlecased](https://angular.io/api/common/TitleCasePipe). But when I change the word `lowercase` to `titlecase` in `my_fragment.html`, it fails. This is what shows in my browser:

```
MyString = {{myCtrl.my_name | lowercase}}
```

And this is the error I see in the Chrome's developer console:
[image]

Why won't `titlecase` work? How can I get it to work??

Comment: Where in the link I provided do you see it is for Angular 2+? I don't see the version number clearly stated in there. Can I just change the script src tag in my html by replacing 1.6.4 with 2.0.0 to make this filter work??

Comment: Mind including the error in text or code format rather than image. There is a link in error, will give you more information about it. As I can see you trying to inject some wrong dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you provided is for Angular 2+ you are using AngularJS (1.X), so that pipe does not exist however you can create your own titlecase function like so

```
function titleCase(str) {
  return str.toLowerCase().replace(/\b\S/g, function(t) { return t.toUpperCase() });
}
```

and implement it like so...

```
MyString = titleCase(myCtrl.my_name)
```

you may have to do `myCtrl.titleCase(myCtrl.my_name)` if the above does not work.

Comment: Where in the link I provided do you see it is for Angular 2+? I don't see the version number clearly stated in there. Can I just change the script src tag in my html by replacing 1.6.4 with 2.0.0 to make this filter work??

Comment: So a while ago, angular changed completely so angular before the change is angularJS and angular after the change is Angular. So yes they have the same name but they are completely different, these are the docs for angularJS https://docs.angularjs.org/api. Angular 2 is a different type of framework you cant just add the script, you have to use the angular cli detailed here https://cli.angular.io/

Comment: This is your easiest solution

Comment: more like `myCtrl.titleCase(...)` no?

Comment: @tanmay No because you have to pass in `myCtrl.my_name` to the function and it returns the value

Comment: @SmokeyDawson I am saying you'd need to prepend `myCtrl.` to your function call. It's using controllerAs syntax right? Unless the function gets declared in scope, I think you'd need `myCtrl.titleCase(myCtrl.my_name)`

Comment: @tanmay yes sorry my mistake, I have updated my answer

Comment: Please correct this answer with the following
`return str.toLowerCase().replace(/\b\S/g, function(t) { return t.toUpperCase() });` otherwise it ONLY capitalizes the first letter of each word without lower-casing the other letters. After you make that change, I will mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided was to the `titlecase` pipe in the Angular 2+ docs. However, only the [`lowercase`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/lowercase) and [`uppercase`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/uppercase) filters appear to exist in AngularJS (Angular 1.x), which is what you are using.

You will probably have to implement the `titlecase` filter on your own.

Comment: Where in the link I provided do you see it is for Angular 2+? I don't see the version number clearly stated in there. Can I just change the script src tag in my html by replacing 1.6.4 with 2.0.0 to make this filter work??

Comment: @SaqibAli The Angular.io website refers to documentation Angular 2+. AngularJS (i.e., Angular 1.x) is vastly different than Angular 2+, so you cannot simply change the script source (nor is it very easy to migrate to Angular 2+). You can find many articles online about the difference between the two versions, such as [this one](https://magenic.com/thinking/angular-2-vs-angularjs-1-which-to-choose).

Answer (score 0):

You could write a filter like this with the angular version (**v1.6.4**) you have chosen to work. This way, it will be available for you to use throughout the app.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.msg = 'hello, world. this is a title case example.';
});

app.filter('titlecase', function() {
    return function(input) {
      if (!input || typeof input !== 'string') {
        return '';
      }

      return input.toLowerCase().split(' ').map(value => {
        return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.substring(1);
      }).join(' ');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
</script>
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <p><b>Filter:</b> {{msg | titlecase}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```